# Unable to verify JWT token with ECDSA P512 Public key getting System.PlatformNotSupportedException always

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, cryptography, .net-4.8, ecdsa

I am trying to validate a token is valid or not using ECDSA NIST P-512 public key using C# in .NET Framework 4.8 on Windows 10 OS.

But I keep getting this exception, saying the Platform is not supported.

```cs
System.PlatformNotSupportedException: The specified curve 'nistP521' or its parameters are not valid for this platform. ---> System.Security.Cryptography.CryptographicException: The parameter is incorrect.

   at System.Security.Cryptography.NCryptNative.ImportKey(SafeNCryptProviderHandle provider, Byte[] keyBlob, String format, IntPtr pParametersList)
   at System.Security.Cryptography.ECCng.ImportKeyBlob(String blobType, Byte[] keyBlob, String curveName, SafeNCryptProviderHandle provider)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Security.Cryptography.ECCng.ImportKeyBlob(String blobType, Byte[] keyBlob, String curveName, SafeNCryptProviderHandle provider)
   at System.Security.Cryptography.CngKey.Import(Byte[] keyBlob, String curveName, CngKeyBlobFormat format, CngProvider provider)
   at System.Security.Cryptography.ECCng.ImportKeyBlob(Byte[] blob, String curveName, CngKeyBlobFormat format, ECCurveType curveType)
   at System.Security.Cryptography.ECDsaCng.ImportParameters(ECParameters parameters)
   at System.Security.Cryptography.ECDsa.Create(ECParameters parameters)
   at ConsoleApp3.Program.Main(String[] args) in C:\Users\kmukherjee\source\repos\ConsoleApp3\ConsoleApp3\Program.cs:line 30
```

This is the code I'm trying to replicate in a console application

```cs
using Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Security.Claims;
using System.Security.Cryptography;
using System.Text;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsoleApp3
{
    internal class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string token = @"eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJFUzUxMiJ9.eyJhdWQiOiJPUkNBIiwiYWNjZXNzUmlnaHRJZCI6IjE2ZDlmMGU3LWFmYzMtZWQxMS1hOGUwLTAwMjI0ODFlMGM4MSIsImlzcyI6IlNNQV9BbmRyb2lkIiwiZXhwIjoxNjgwMDg3MjcxLCJpYXQiOjE2ODAwMDA4NzQsImp0aSI6IjUyMjM1ZjZjLTAxZjUtNDRhMS04N2UxLTQwYTU3MWY4YWM3NCJ9.AM4kbafsnXxtVHvIEjZ0dt6Q7fI0xXY_zTmkrsiSrD4sfB2Uy-WRnjLLPTH9Jt_RQ9YuHnSalFcRxizqh8sZjYsaAU1cj3qzWnfx2JdM0McAVoufIDzK8V6LUmiNQoBtStAGy5-QQBgA7VaqG8wRtooeHoFlE6gNqi1cYAynveZIdA6m";

            try
            {
                const string es512PublicKey = @"-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----\nMIGbMBAGByqGSM49AgEGBSuBBAAjA4GGAAQB7yWOe2Q7FiOtrNw10l+a8CDnmDug\n1MUpuvW6SWuRicmK/fqM9gAqVLLNZx2AeniCSAW5kcvdT1AjAHi31RYK/aQA4Vdl\nIqtDRCnEwDqwrRN+IYMC1zwDvyfPS6yhe91uynZ1rWZJpF8wC2in1x+GdQTrbYpX\ni5p91BXzF3sPWuB1XzA=\n-----END PUBLIC KEY-----";


                string pemData = es512PublicKey
                .Replace("-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----", "")
                .Replace("-----END PUBLIC KEY-----", "")
                .Replace("\\n", "");

                byte[] keyBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(pemData);



                ECDsa ecdsa = ECDsa.Create(new ECParameters
                {
                    Curve = ECCurve.NamedCurves.nistP521,
                    Q = new ECPoint
                    {
                        X = keyBytes.Skip(1).Take(66).ToArray(),
                        Y = keyBytes.Skip(67).Take(66).ToArray()
                    }
                });

                JwtSecurityTokenHandler jwtHandler = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler();
                JwtSecurityToken jwtToken = jwtHandler.ReadJwtToken(token);

                // Verify the signature using the ECDSA public key
                TokenValidationParameters validationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
                {
                    ValidateIssuer = true,
                    ValidIssuer = "SMA_iOS",
                    ValidateAudience = false,
                    ValidateLifetime = true,
                    IssuerSigningKey = new ECDsaSecurityKey(ecdsa)
                };

                ClaimsPrincipal claimsPrincipal = jwtHandler.ValidateToken(jwtToken.RawData, validationParameters, out var validatedToken);

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
               Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

any help would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `X` and `Y` coordinates are located at the end of the DER encoded X.509/SPKI key:

```cs
...                      
X = keyBytes.Skip(keyBytes.Length - 2 * 66).Take(66).ToArray(), // in .NET Core SkipLast() can be applied...
Y = keyBytes.Skip(keyBytes.Length - 66).Take(66).ToArray()
...
```

Also, the issuer is wrong, disable the validation (`ValidateIssuer = false`) or specify the correct issuer (`ValidIssuer = "SMA_Android"`).

With these fixes validation is successful and `validatedToken` is:

```
{"typ":"JWT","alg":"ES512"}.{"aud":"ORCA","accessRightId":"16d9f0e7-afc3-ed11-a8e0-0022481e0c81","iss":"SMA_Android","exp":1680087271,"iat":1680000874,"jti":"52235f6c-01f5-44a1-87e1-40a571f8ac74"}
```

---

**Edit:**

The key you posted is a PEM encoded public EC key in X.509/SPKI format. A key of this format can be decoded with an ASN.1 parser, e.g. https://lapo.it/asn1js/ (note: disable the *with definitions* option).
The raw public key in uncompressed format <0x04> | x | y (x and y are 66 bytes each for P-521) is at the end, i.e. for P-521 the last 133 bytes. From this x and y can be determined.
In this way, x and y were determined in the above code snippet (and from them the EC key).

---

The *direct* import of a PEM (or even a DER encoded) key is not so easy with .NET Framework, because unlike .NET Core, .NET Framework practically does not support this at all. A convenient way to import a PEM encoded key with .NET Framework is `PemReader` from BouncyCastle:

Example:

```cs
using Org.BouncyCastle.Crypto.Parameters;
using Org.BouncyCastle.OpenSsl;

...

string spkiPem = @"-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----
                   MIGbMBAGByqGSM49AgEGBSuBBAAjA4GGAAQB7yWOe2Q7FiOtrNw10l+a8CDnmDug
                   1MUpuvW6SWuRicmK/fqM9gAqVLLNZx2AeniCSAW5kcvdT1AjAHi31RYK/aQA4Vdl
                   IqtDRCnEwDqwrRN+IYMC1zwDvyfPS6yhe91uynZ1rWZJpF8wC2in1x+GdQTrbYpX
                   i5p91BXzF3sPWuB1XzA=
                   -----END PUBLIC KEY-----";
TextReader textReader = new StringReader(spkiPem);
ECPublicKeyParameters ecPubKeyParams = (ECPublicKeyParameters)new PemReader(textReader).ReadObject();

ECDsa ecdsa = ECDsa.Create(new ECParameters
{
    Curve = ECCurve.NamedCurves.nistP521,
    Q = new ECPoint
    {
        X = ecPubKeyParams.Q.AffineXCoord.GetEncoded(), 
        Y = ecPubKeyParams.Q.AffineYCoord.GetEncoded()  
    }
});
```

Comment: Thank you its working now, can you please elaborate more your answer on the mistake I was doing for X and Y co-ordinates.

Also as I am using .NET Framework 4.8 on windows does it use Openssl or the windows crypto library to read the pem file, can you please add more details to your answer.

Comment: @KunalMukherjee - I have elaborated on the import a little deeper, s. the Edit section in my answer.